# Connect LoopBack app to existing MySQL database

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a local MySQL database `mydb`.  It contains a table called `person`, with fields `id` (primary key, integer auto-increment) and `name` (text).  The table contains records that I do not want to delete.

I want a LoopBack app that connects to `mydb` through a data source `myds`.  The app should have a model `Person` (which extends `PersistedModel`).  CRUD operations on the `Person` model should be reflected on the `people` table of `mydb`.

How do I build the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an empty application with the application generator.

```
>lb
? What's the name of your application? myapp 
? Enter name of the directory to contain the project: myapp
? Which version of LoopBack would you like to use? 3.x (current)
? What kind of application do you have in mind? empty-server
```

Add a new datasource:

```
/* /server/datasources.json */
  "myds": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "mydb",
    "password": "password",
    "name": "myds",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
```

Install loopback-connector-mysql:

```
> npm install loopback-connector-mysql --save
```

Create a model

```
/* /common/models/Person.json */
{
  "name": "Person",
  "plural": "People",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Then attach the model to the data source.

```
/* /server/model-config.json */
{
  // ...
  "Person": {
    "dataSource": "myds",
    "public": true
  }
  //...
}
```

The app is complete.  To run the app,

```
> node .
```

Then navigate to `localhost:3000/explorer` in a browser.  Click on the `Person` model, then click on the route GET `/People`, then click "try it out!"  The app should return all rows in the `person` table from the database.  The other CRUD operations should also function properly.

Note that the naming is very important.  When we connect a model named `Person` and to the datasource `myds`, which itself connects to the database `mydb`, LoopBack looks for a table called `Person` in mydb (this may interact with case-sensitivty of table names in your MySQL installation), with exactly the properties of `Person` as its field names.